# Balls disappearing when adding other balls on canvas

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a game where you shoot a ball in the direction of the cursor click.
I have two classes: `Game` class and `Ball` class. The `Game` class created `Balls` and then the `Ball` class animates the balls. It works but when I clear the canvas, it also clears the previous balls although I am pushing new balls to the array.

This is the code from the `Game` class:

```
class Game {
    constructor(props) {
        // ...
        this.balls = []
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {        
            this.handleMouseClicks(this.canvas, e)
        });
    }

    handleMouseClicks(canvas, e) {             
         this.balls.push(new Ball())
   }
}
```

And the `Ball` class:

```
class Ball {
    constructor(props) {
        // ...
        this.animateBall()
    }
    animateBall() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0,0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animateBall)        
        this.drawBall()
        this.updateBall()
    }

    updateBall() {   
        this.ballPosX = this.ballPosX + this.velocity.x
        this.ballPosY = this.ballPosY + this.velocity.y
    }

    drawBall() {           
        this.angle = Math.atan2(this.mouseClickPosY - this.cannonPosY, this.mouseClickPosX - this.cannonPosX)
        this.velocity = {
            x: Math.cos(this.angle),
            y: Math.sin(this.angle)
        }
        this.ballRadius = 2
        this.ctx.beginPath()
        this.ctx.arc(this.ballPosX, this.ballPosY, this.ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
        this.ctx.closePath()
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        this.ctx.fill()
}
```

Comment: Your `animateBall` method clears the entire canvas, so every time you draw a ball, you remove all previous balls. You should probably have your `requestAnimationFrame` and canvas clear outside the Ball class

Comment: Thank you, where should I do it? Because even if I put it outside it would clear the entire canvas no? It's weird because I'm following this video and for him it did not delete everything: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI9idPTT0c4

Comment: You want to clear the canvas every frame or else the previous positions of the balls will be visible.
I'd suggest setting up a game loop that calls `animateBall` for each ball, and then calls `requestAnimationFrame` with itself as the argument (as you're currently doing in `animateBall`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd put it as an answer as code is easier to format. Move your game loop to the `Game` class:

```
class Game {
    constructor(props) {
        // ...
        this.balls = []
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {        
            this.handleMouseClicks(this.canvas, e)
        });
        // start the game loop
        this.gameLoop()
    }

    gameLoop() {
        // clear the canvas
        this.ctx.clearRect(0,0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
        // draw all the balls
        this.balls.forEach((ball) => {
            ball.animateBall();
        });
        // call the next iteration
        requestAnimationFrame(this.gameLoop);
    }

    handleMouseClicks(canvas, e) {             
         this.balls.push(new Ball())
   }
}
```

And then `animateBall` can just be:

```
animateBall() {       
    this.drawBall()
    this.updateBall()
}
```

(Make sure to remove the call to this.animateBall from the Ball constructor)

Comment: It tells me `;` is expected but I can't find where

Comment: I missed the closing bracket for the `gameLoop` method. I've updated it so it should work now

Comment: Thank you, it's almost working, I just couldn't use the exact `gameLoop` code because my code is different and I'm having scope issues with the animation. However, if I manually click on the canvas it keeps moving so it's OK. So the disappearing balls issue is solved. This is my new post if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70125569/how-to-make-the-balls-move-on-canvas-instead-of-manually-moving-on-each-click.