# How to make the balls move on canvas instead of manually moving on each click

Tags: javascript

I am working on a game where on each click on the canvas, the player (positioned on the canvas) shoots a ball in that direction. Right now what's working is that when ever I click on the canvas, it creates the ball and it advances as I keep clicking, but it should move forward automatically after the first click. I tried using `requestAnimationFrame` but I'm having scope issues.

This is the code that is relevant:
The `Game` class:

```
class Game {
    constructor(props) {
        // ...
        this.balls = []
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {        
            this.handleMouseClicks(this.canvas, e)
        });
    }

    handleMouseClicks(canvas, e) {
        if () {
        } else {
            this.balls.push(new Ball());
            this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
            // draw all the balls
            this.balls.forEach((ball) => {
                ball.animateBall();
            });
            // draw the player after clearing the canvas
            this.player.drawPlayer(this.playerPosX, this.playerPosY);
        }
             
         
   }
}
```

The `Ball` class:

```
    class Ball {
        constructor(props) {
            // ...
           
        }

        updateBall() {   
            this.ballPosX = this.ballPosX + this.velocity.x
            this.ballPosY = this.ballPosY + this.velocity.y
        }

        drawBall() {           
            this.angle = Math.atan2(this.mouseClickPosY - this.cannonPosY, this.mouseClickPosX - this.cannonPosX);
            this.velocity = {
                x: Math.cos(this.angle),
                y: Math.sin(this.angle)
            };
            this.ballRadius = 2;
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.arc(this.ballPosX, this.ballPosY, this.ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            this.ctx.closePath();
            this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            this.ctx.fill();
}
    
        animateBall() {
            this.drawBall();
            this.updateBall(); 
        }
    }
```

What I tried to do was to move the animation part inside Game class so that I can call it using `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
    handleMouseClicks(canvas, e) {
        if () {
        } else {
          loop();
 
          function loop(){
             this.balls.push(new Ball());
             this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
             // draw all the balls
             this.balls.forEach((ball) => {
             ball.animateBall();
            });
            // draw the player after clearing the canvas
            this.player.drawPlayer(this.playerPosX, this.playerPosY);

          requestAnimationFrame(loop);
          }

        }
}
```

But that is not working as intended

Comment: Define "scope issues"? I don't see any `requestAnimationFrame` in your code

Comment: *"I tried using requestAnimationFrame but I'm having scope issues."* Shows us what you've tried and what error you got.

Comment: Thank you guys, I edited the post and added what I tried at the bottom.

Comment: *Update: I also added the code for the `drawBall` and `updateBall` so you get a sense of what's going on there. Thank you!

Comment: Any chance you can add some workable code in a snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a function using the `function` keyword it will be defined in the global scope. If you want the function to use the Game instance as `this`, you can use an arrow function. [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) bind the function's context to the context they are defined in.

Let's define a `draw()` method to the `Game` class.

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    // ...
    this.draw();
  }

  // ...

  draw() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    
    // draw all the balls
    this.balls.forEach((ball) => {
      ball.animateBall();
    });

    // draw the player after clearing the canvas
    this.player.drawPlayer(this.playerPosX, this.playerPosY);

    // Here, "() => { /* function body */ }" is an arrow function example
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.draw());
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I tried that as well, but it will not start animating, it just waits for the next click. Maybe I am placing it in the wrong place in the class?

Comment: it works, I accidentally opened a copy of the file and saved the changes there, so the actual file that was running on localhost did not update, now it's ok, thank you!